# How to override grails implicit log variable

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, grails-controller, grails-4

I am having a grails application where I get a log variable in controller and service folders implicitly. However, I have my own logger that I want to use across the application. How can I override that grails implicit log variable?

Comment: Are you wanting the `log` property in all of your controllers and services to point to the same logger instance?

Comment: Yes I want that log instance to point to my custom logger and all log messages must come through that custom logger only.

Comment: Sharing a single instance across the app is an unusual thing to want to do.  Can you summarize why that would be helpful?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't really just want each of the separate loggers to share an appender?

Comment: I dont need the single instance. I just want to use my custom logger in place of grails provided slf4j log instance. I tried to override the log variable like below. but it didnt work out because the log variable is final.....
What I tried -->
(log = new CustomLogger(Action.class))

Comment: Does your property have to be called `log`?

Comment: Yes I want it as log

Answer (score 2):

> How can I override that grails implicit log variable?

If you omit the `org.grails:grails-logging` plugin, the default provided logger won't be introduced.  At that point you could define your own `log` property and do what you want with it.  If you want to automatically add your own `log` property to all of your controllers and services you could do that a number of ways.  One would be to write an AST transformation.  Another would be to write a trait that provides your logger property and then have your classes implement that trait, either explicitly, or by way of `@Enhances`.